# Ionic 3 - use iOS style on android for selected components

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, styles, toast

I am developing an application with the use of Ionic 3. 
I would like my app to look the same on all platforms and I want to use a kind of a mix of android and ios styles. 
In general, I will go for android (md) mode of the app, but I want to override certain elements to have ios styles.
For example, I would like my toasts, popovers and alert to have ios style and transition animations.
I can't seem to find a way to do it, please help :)
Thank you